# ngrx: Use variable from previous selector to compare

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I created a poor mans update polling mechanism. It checks for updates on an URL, and then dispatches a message to update the object. This work, but now I only want to dispatch this update when the object has changed, because maybe the object was already up to date. To be able to verify these objects, I created a hash: if the hashes are equal, so are the objects.

Now, this effect works fine:

```js
@Effect()
pollBatStore = this.actions$
  .ofType(BatStoresActions.POLL_BAT_STORE)
  .map((action: BatStoresActions.PollBatStore) => action.payload)
  .mergeMap((upd: BatUpdateJSON) => this.batStoreStorage.getBatStoreFromUrl(upd['_links'].pollUrl.href))
  .map((batStore: BatStore) => {
    return new UpdateBatStore(batStore);
  });
```

But obviously, this will always update my object in the store when an update notification comes in. So I want to compare the object that I fetch from my API with the object that I have in my ngrx store. Now, how can I combine the objects so I can compare their properties?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```js
@Effect()
pollBatStore = this.actions$
  .ofType(BatStoresActions.POLL_BAT_STORE)
  .map((action: BatStoresActions.PollBatStore) => action.payload)
  .mergeMap((upd: BatUpdateJSON) => this.batStoreStorage.getBatStoreFromUrl(upd['_links'].pollUrl.href))
  .withLatestFrom((bs: BatStore) => this.batStoreRepository.getBatStoreByApiKey(bs.apiKey))
  .map(([batStore: BatStore, batStoreInMemory: BatStore]) => {
    if (batStore.apiHash !== batStoreInMemory.apiHash) {
      return new UpdateBatStore(batStore);
    } else {
      return {type: 'NO_ACTION'}
    }
  });
```

I think I'm using .withLatestFrom in the wrong way, but I need the apiKey property from my object to be able to select it. So I guess I need another selector, but which one? I can't figure it out.

**Update**: this seems to be working now, but I think it's an awful solution. Especially passing and checking the 'false' return value two times. But it does what I want: when the hash in the ngrx store is the same as my REST api tells me, it doesn't update.

```js
@Effect()
pollBatStore = this.actions$
  .ofType(BatStoresActions.POLL_BAT_STORE)
  .map((action: BatStoresActions.PollBatStore) => action.payload)
  .switchMap((upd: BatUpdateJSON) => {
    return this.batStoreRepository.getBatStoreByApiKey(upd.apiKey)
      .take(1)
      .map((bs: BatStore) => {
        console.log('Found batstore in mem: ', bs);
        if (upd.apiHash !== bs.apiHash) {
          return bs;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
  })
  .switchMap(result => {
    console.log('Result from hash check ', result);
    if (result instanceof BatStore) {
      return this.batStoreStorage.getBatStoreFromUrl(result.links['self'].href)
        .take(1)
        .map(newBs => {
          console.log('New object: ', newBs);
          return newBs;
        });
    } else {
      return Observable.of(false);
    }
  })
  .map(result => {
    console.log('Final result', result);
    if (result instanceof BatStore) {
      return new UpdateBatStore(result);
    } else {
      return new NoAction();
    }
  });
```

Comment: "doesn't work": do you mean it errors? or it still updates store every time?
Also, what is the return type of this.batStoreRepository.getBatStoreByApiKey? Observable<BatStore>?

Comment: Yes, it said "," expected, so I changed the last selector to `.map(([batStore, batStoreInMemory]) => ...` but then it said `Type Observable<BatStore> is not an array type`. Both get methods return an Observable<BatStore>: batStoreStorage loads data from our REST API, batStoreRepository loads from ngrx store.

Answer (score 0):

A few months later I found out that forkJoin is probably a better solution. At first I didn't get this to work, because selecting an object from the ngrx store returns an Observable that doesn't complete ([source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3054#issuecomment-342631717)). So forkJoin never completes either. Adding a .take(1) solved this problem.

So I rewrote my effect, and now it looks like this:

```
@Effect()
pollBatStore = this.actions$
  .ofType(BatStoresActions.POLL_BAT_STORE)
  .pipe(
    map((action: BatStoresActions.PollBatStore) => action.payload),
    mergeMap((upd: BatUpdateJSON) => forkJoin(
      of(upd),
      this.batStoreRepository.getBatStoreByApiKey(upd.apiKey)
    )),
    filter(([upd, batStore]) => {
      return upd.apiHash !== batStore.apiHash;
    }),
    mergeMap(([upd, batStore]) => {
      return this.batStoreStorage.getBatStoreFromUrl(upd._links.pollUrl.href);
    }),
    map(newBatStore => new UpdateBatStore(newBatStore))
  );
```

I'm not sure though if this is the correct answer, but I thought it could be helpful to share anyways. One thing I'm still wondering about is that I thought an effect should always return an action. This code works without errors, but what happens if the chain stops at the filter?